# Will TcpClient.Available throw or not?

Tags: .net, exception, tcpclient

The [docs at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available.aspx) contain this sentence which is rather ambigous:

> If the remote host shuts down or closes the connection, Available may
>   throw a SocketException.

What does that mean? The docs are not clear.

What determines if the Available property will throw or not?

Comment: The behavior of the remote host and even external factors (cat ate network cable, etc). For you, this means that you must assume that `Available` can always throw. Isn't that clear?

Comment: MSDN literally means that it `may` throw a SocketException or `may not`. You cannot really know the status of a socket till you try to send something through it.

Comment: It's clear what the verb ''may'' means. What is not clear is in what cases would Available throw an exception. Other than 'An error occurred when attempting to access the socket.', which does not explan what kind of error.

Answer (score 2):

> What does that mean?

That you need to wrap it in a `try..catch` block, because it *may* throw an exception.

Furthermore I think the *when* will be an implementation detail. Decompile the System.Net assembly to see for yourself when it does throw.

I suspect it won't throw if the remote party properly shut down the socket (and that in that case `0` will be returned), but that is not something you can rely on.